# Reliable check for active session on app startup in Facebook iOS SDK v4.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, session

I am creating an iOS App with Facebook iOS SDK 4.0, using a simple Facebook login dialog with the `FBSDKLoginButton` view class.

When starting the app after a previous successful login, the button correctly appears in "logged in" state, i.e. displaying the text "Log out".

However, `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` is nil, which is why my App is unconscious of the active session and thus does not populate the FB-related fields with data.

Since the `FBSession` class no longer exists with FB iOS SDK4.0, how can I correctly determine whether a cached session exists?

I assumed that `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` was the way to do it. But, as mentioned, the `currentAccessToken` is not set... Any ideas why it could be nil, or how to correctly detect an active/cached session?

EDIT: I have put the call to `currentAccessToken` in the `viewDidLoad` method of my main view controller, which contains the Facebook login dialog ad button. Unfortunately, the currentAccessToken is nil, as described above. Any suggestions why it is not available?

EDIT2: Bigman solved the issue (see his comments in his answer below): Getting the `currentAccessToken` in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get this token is you will want to provide a delegate this FBSDKLoginButton.
I make one of my view controller conform to FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate and I implemented

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    let token = result.token

    println(token)
}
```

In the storyboard, I set this view controller to the FBSDKLoginButton. The token is not nil at runtime.

[My second attempt]

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    let token = result.token

    let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()

    println(accessToken)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I did exactly that. I am writing in objective-c, and not using storyboards though, but otherwise I had already done what you suggested. Still, no cached token available on startup.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint inside the function and see if it breaks?

Comment: Yes, the actual log-in works perfectly. My problem is that when I restart the app after successful login, there is no cached token. I.e. the currentAccessToken is nil, even though the FBSDKLoginButton shows the logged-in state, indicating that the session is still running.

Comment: By the way, even the `FBSDKProfilePictureView` correctly displays the user that was last logged in, but still the currentAccessToken is nil.

Comment: That is very weird. See I posted some more code. This way I do get the accessToken which is not nil. From the debugger the token and accessToken are essentially the same object. The language is Swift which Apple developed upon objective-C. The issue should not come from language difference

Comment: What is the "result" parameter's value? Is it also nil?

Comment: I have no problems with the `loginButton:didCompleteWithResult` method... it gets called and result is not nil.

Comment: My problem is that inside `viewDidLoad`, the currentAccessToken is nil.

Comment: I see. Get the currentAccessToken in viewDidAppear then. When the view is being load, all its subviews including the Facebook button are not loaded yet

Comment: Yes, that did it! Getting the `currentAccessToken` in `viedDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` appears to be the way to go. Thanks a lot for your help and patience!

Answer (score 9):

So I just ran into this myself.

Goal: On app launch, if a token has already been acquired from a previous successful login attempt, do some alternative logic (in my case, launching directly to a different view controller).

The key here is what Dheeraj brought up originally.

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

The minute you call out to their shared delegate, that is when they wake up everything. So code example. This might be a really bad practice, I'm unsure, this is just how I got it to work.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [FBSDKLoginButton class];
  [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
  NSLog(@"What the heck, no token? %@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]);
  //Output: What the heck, no token? (nil)
  BOOL fbDidFinish = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  NSLog(@"Hey! My Token! %@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]);
  //Output: Hey! My Token! <FBSDKAccessToken: 0x7fddf8d136a0>
  //Your address in memory will be different
  //At this point, you can do additional logic based on having the Token, like skipping ahead to a different ViewController
  return fbDidFinish;
}
```

Assuming you've already successfully logged in once before, you should see your access token on the second log output. Hope this helps.

Comment: reason why my token = nil?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

This would get you [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] when user is logged in.

Refer to : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#startcoding

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I have already "connected" the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` as you described. I also implemented the method application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:, and connected it to the FBSDKApplicationDelegate. Still, the currentAccessToken is nil on startup, even though the FBSDKLoginButton displays its logged-in state.